# Arfoundation Black Screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I have been working with arfoundation for quite a bit now, but all of a sudden when I built a new project, I am ending up with a black screen.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.ads": "2.0.8",
    "com.unity.analytics": "3.3.2",
    "com.unity.collab-proxy": "1.2.16",
    "com.unity.package-manager-ui": "2.1.2",
    "com.unity.purchasing": "2.0.6",
    "com.unity.textmeshpro": "2.0.1",
    "com.unity.timeline": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.xr.arcore": "2.1.2",
    "com.unity.xr.arfoundation": "2.1.4",
    "com.unity.xr.arkit": "2.1.2",
    "com.unity.modules.ai": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.animation": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.assetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.audio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.cloth": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.director": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imageconversion": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imgui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.jsonserialize": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.particlesystem": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics2d": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.screencapture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrain": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrainphysics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.tilemap": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.ui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.uielements": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.umbra": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unityanalytics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vehicles": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.video": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vr": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.wind": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.xr": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have also unchecked arcore and arkit support. I dont know what else to do,

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Build Settings -> Player Settings -> XR Plug-In Managment -> Select ArCore in Android Tab.[Android's tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s0ku.png)
If you're also developing for iOS, select ARKit in iOS tab.

Comment: than you savior <3

Answer (score 1):

We need more informations about your problem. Which version of Unity are you using ? Did you tried to run your project on both iOS and Android ? Still the same problem ? Did you tried to run any ARFoundation sample to see if it's related to your project, your Unity etc ... ?

Comment: I am using unity version 2019.1.8f1. Yes I have run both on iOS and android.Same problem.

I was using the same in another,and the project is running fine.

Comment: So it seems it's related to your project ... Have you changed anything in your project settings ? Do you build with IL2CPP or Mono ? I think the best way for you is to start from a working project (e.g ARFoundation samples) and add all your project step by step and check if it's working at each step. I know it's a lot of work, but without more details, I have no other solution and it's the way I would proceed.

Comment: I am using mono,and if I start from the project that is already working its still working,but dont understand what changed. 
I am following this tutorial

and used https://github.com/TheUnityWorkbench/tuw-arfoundation-demo

still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my AR Foundation package to 3.0 and changed settings for XR-Plugin Management relevant to AR-Kit. Worked for me.